# Querying Access database in SharePoint folder, creates a ".laccdb" file in Recycle bin

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

As in the subject line, running a SELECT statement on this database from an Excel macro puts a ".laccdb" file in the recycle bin - is there any way to avoid this?

VBA:

```
Sub QueryDbOnSP()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim cnStr As String
    Dim qryStr As String
    Dim WebDavStr As String
    
    WebDavStr = "\\....\myDbName.accdb"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & WebDavStr
    qryStr = "SELECT * FROM [Table1];"
    cn.Open cnStr
    Set rs = cn.Execute(qryStr)
    'rest of code

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not. This may be normal behavior. Read what this says about use of Recycle Bin by SharePoint https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-link-or-move-data-to-sharepoint-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee#bkmk_advantages

Comment: Thanks for this, @June7. The Recycle Bin part of this article refers to a database linked to a SharePoint list and how you can view and recover records that were deleted. My database is not linked to any lists, it just sits in a SharePoint folder and a simple Select statement puts the .laccdb file (not records) in the bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly *how* you're querying Access, you can query in exclusive mode.

Exclusive mode locks the file and thus doesn't create and delete a .laccdb file since the entire file is locked.

For an OLEDB connection, you connect in exclusive mode by adding `Mode=Share Exclusive;` to the connection string.

However, SharePoint auto-deletes these files anyway (depending on configuration, but usually). It auto-mails you about these files if you delete many, but a simple mail rule blocks these or puts them into a low-priority mailbox.

Comment: thank you, I added my code in the original post. Also, did a bit of research on "exclusive mode" after your answer but did not find a solution.

Comment: For whoever reads this in the future - the locking of the database file that comes with the exclusive mode is not something that can be disregarded. What I saw in my testing today was that, when the database file got locked by user A running the code to read the data and, while it was locked for these few seconds, user B tried to access it by running their code, user B got an error, but, more worryingly, the database file went into a permanent "checked out" state and needed to be deleted from SharePoint and added again (it couldn't even be overridden, had to be deleted).

Comment: @tsdn Note that Access does NOT support multiple users accessing the same database at the same time over anything but SMB (and even with SMB, [beware](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-reports-that-databases-are-in-an-inconsistent-state-7ec975da-f7a9-4414-a306-d3a7c422dc1d). If you have multiple users using the same database while it's stored on SharePoint, that's trouble, if you use exclusive locks you get a locking conflict which leaves it "checked out", if you don't, you can get conflicts in the database file itself which can leave your database damaged with file loss.

Comment: Thank you, @Erik A, I was completely unaware of this, the _Access db on SharePoint_ solution was suggested to me by an IT guy in the office and I didn't for a moment think to doubt him. The good news is that from January, we'll be moving to a SQL database. In the meantime, I'll figure out how to prevent multiple users accessing at the same time.